# Intelligent closest match detection with names in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a MySQL table like the one below with a list of names in an organisation, and IDs for each.

```
id      name
1       John Doe
2       Richard Smith
3       Jane Market
...     ...
```

Given user will query for the person's first and/or last name (with the possibility of typos and nicknames used) and php should return the closest match to their query.

For example, if a user enters "ricky" (nickname for Richard), it should return the ID for Richard Smith.

Comment: Sounds cool. What have you tried?

Comment: So you need to add new column for synonyms

Comment: It would be much easier, and maybe more useful to the user, to load 5-10 names as they type using ajax, based on the letters they have typed so far, not worrying about typos.

Comment: Typos can be solved via something like this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php. Someone adds and extra character or gets a name slightly wrong. (Adds a J instead of a K but has everything else right) it will return something close in the array. Not sure how you'd go about the synonyms or short names for longer names.

Answer (score 0):

For nicknames, you have to create a separate MySQL table, with lookups (Many-to-One relationship).

For typos, you will have to loop all of your names and compare them to what the user has entered using the [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.levenshtein.php) function, or the [similar_text](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.similar-text.php) function. The User Contributed Notes will help.